# MongoDb find do not returns the documents that match the filter criteria

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, backend

I am working on a project and i want to show the welcome post to each member of the family only once, once the family started following the other family, For example when family1 becomes the follower of family2 then family1 all members will be shown a welcome post on their timeline only once.
I am using this logic to store each memberId in an array in database and once that member seen the post i will remove that specific member id from that memberIds array preety simple.
But i am getting wrong results when i am trying to fetch the welcome post related to a specific member
I think i might be wrong with my find() function but after hours of searching i am unable to find the bug Help me with this

Here is the code of my controller file

```
const welcomePosts = await postService.getTextPost(
            {
                $match: {
                    familyId: user.familyId,
                    memberIds: user._id,
                    isWelcomePost: true
                }
            }
        );
        console.log("Welcome post :", welcomePosts);

        if (welcomePosts.length) {
            await postService.updateTextPost(
                {
                    "_id": { $in: welcomePosts.map(post => post._id) }
                },
                {
                    $pull: {
                        'memberIds': user._id
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        return response
            .status(200)
            .json({
                welcomePosts
            });
```

Service file code:

```
const getTextPost = async (query) => {

    console.log("In get text post query");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        text.find(query)
            .then((post) => resolve(post))
            .catch((err) => reject(err));
    });

}
```

The result i am getting first time when user hit the api for first time:

```
"welcomePosts": [
        {
            "_id": "637f78e3285dd157614d56f1",
            "backgroundColor": "blue",
            "alignment": "CENTER",
            "fontSize": "12px",
            "isWelcomePost": true,
            "familyId": "636a46de501de84cb0e2a73b",
            "familyToFollowId": "637c7eb6d09dfe8fcb66161c",
            "memberIds": [
                "637c6f24a4b2d460a9a2ab67",
                "637cbb418176b9ea768d93c0",
                "636a4645501de84cb0e2a734"
            ],
            "description": "Whether you're a newbie or just a refresher, drop-in for an introduction to famlicious followed",
            "postType": "TEXT",
            "visibility": "PUBLIC",
            "__t": "text",
            "createdAt": "2022-11-24T14:00:03.213Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-24T14:00:09.011Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
]
```

The second time when the user hits the api his id from memberIds array will be filtered out but my find query is still fetching

The second time when i hit the same api:

```
"welcomePosts": [
        {
            "_id": "637f78e3285dd157614d56f1",
            "backgroundColor": "blue",
            "alignment": "CENTER",
            "fontSize": "12px",
            "isWelcomePost": true,
            "familyId": "636a46de501de84cb0e2a73b",
            "familyToFollowId": "637c7eb6d09dfe8fcb66161c",
            "memberIds": [
                "637c6f24a4b2d460a9a2ab67",
                "637cbb418176b9ea768d93c0"
            ],
            "description": "Whether you're a newbie or just a refresher, drop-in for an introduction to famlicious followed",
            "postType": "TEXT",
            "visibility": "PUBLIC",
            "__t": "text",
            "createdAt": "2022-11-24T14:00:03.213Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-11-24T14:00:09.011Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
]
```

I want that when the second time that same user hits this api he will not get that welcome post
The response should return empty welcomePost array:

```
{
    "welcomePosts": []
}
```

Comment: What is "`text`" in your service file code? Also, `$match` is for aggregations (e.g. `.aggregate()`), you seem to be using `find()` here

Comment: "text" is the model for text type post like we have posts in IG or FB that are comprised just of text. I tries using the same query with aggregation and it just works perfectly fine for me. Thanks